# Can't display svg in v-icon

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I try to display an svg image in a `v-icon`, but the icon is not visible on my page, i.e I do the following:

```
      <v-icon>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="264" version="1.1" id="svg529">
          <title id="title850">SOFORT ÜBERWEISUNG Logo</title>
          <g transform="matrix(0.54981622,0,0,0.54981622,271.3869,-35.870245)" id="icons--sofortueberweisung">
            <path style="fill:#ee7f00" id="path442"
                  d="m 625.292,167.605 c -7.41,20.141 -20.712,32.601 -46.018,32.601 h -0.094 l -13.093,-0.021 22.378,-60.951 h 12.733 c 23.296,0.016 31.996,6.89 24.094,28.371 m 67.155,-55.678 C 681.069,95.374 657.904,87.245 621.621,87.21 h -84 l -90.857,252.033 h 77.179 l 33.024,-88.717 c 1.612,3.639 21.104,88.717 21.104,88.717 h 81.123 c 0,0 -14.754,-62.517 -25.606,-87.769 -2.793,-6.482 -5.7,-13.765 -9.581,-19.834 22.913,-8.604 56.115,-27.062 69.86,-64.49 8.454,-23.004 7.961,-41.574 -1.42,-55.223 M -83.01,87.063 h -143.074 c -22.562,0 -44.463,0 -64.102,10.055 -19.636,10.07 -36.959,30.211 -50.306,70.482 -2.892,8.669 -4.426,16.125 -4.619,22.592 -0.199,6.513 0.914,12.027 3.345,16.829 3.002,5.844 7.869,11.365 13.954,16.012 6.09,4.633 13.386,8.425 21.242,10.84 0.308,0.081 4.434,1.275 9.433,2.707 a 1555.423,1555.423 0 0 1 14.509,4.311 c 2.156,0.667 4.541,1.535 6.697,2.839 2.153,1.29 4.079,3.022 5.3,5.438 a 12.426,12.426 0 0 1 1.274,5.209 c 0.051,1.875 -0.261,3.898 -0.997,6.023 -1.827,5.484 -4.604,8.991 -9.889,11.162 -5.273,2.14 -13.057,2.842 -24.847,2.94 h -147.233 l -23.28,64.574 h 157.604 c 14.82,0 41.935,0 67.987,-11.181 26.053,-11.181 51.042,-33.528 61.617,-78.239 3.985,-16.812 2.759,-30.49 -3.77,-41.245 -6.528,-10.763 -18.364,-18.545 -35.569,-23.54 0,0 -3.853,-1.13 -8.386,-2.45 -4.525,-1.306 -9.734,-2.81 -12.409,-3.589 -4.406,-1.274 -7.787,-3.854 -9.79,-7.134 -1.996,-3.267 -2.6,-7.248 -1.458,-11.315 1.175,-4.208 4.033,-7.587 8.161,-9.906 4.149,-2.314 9.597,-3.589 15.949,-3.589 h 91.606 c 0.638,-0.953 1.223,-1.961 1.875,-2.909 16.738,-23.908 36.992,-43.253 59.176,-56.916"/>
            <path style="fill:#ee7f00" id="path444"
                  d="m -15.805,211.911 c -21.379,59.109 -36.905,73.994 -60.264,73.994 h -0.045 c -22.761,-0.035 -30.739,-14.575 -9.437,-73.402 15.896,-43.925 36.5,-72.022 61.408,-72.022 h 0.016 c 23.703,0.036 29.135,13.904 8.322,71.43 M 57.569,110.674 C 45.096,92.658 23.763,83.495 -5.926,83.465 c -19.43,0 -38.278,4.505 -55.96,12.93 -25.267,12.078 -48.183,32.239 -66.892,58.989 -12.142,17.369 -22.538,37.479 -30.7,59.99 -15.363,42.488 -15.182,76.965 0.522,99.684 8.914,12.833 27.403,28.179 65.029,28.208 h 0.146 c 68.543,0 119.73,-45.377 152.133,-134.878 8.554,-23.7 19.852,-67.886 -0.783,-97.714 M 331.489,87.063 H 185.676 c -40.763,0 -71.104,20.829 -85.44,59.825 L 30.979,339.075 h 75.87 l 35.585,-98.807 67.054,0.055 19.068,-52.909 -66.831,-0.046 10.756,-30.64 c 2.256,-5.483 7.609,-9.856 15.46,-9.856 4.362,0 53.573,0.015 79.057,0.031 0.652,-0.948 1.24,-1.977 1.893,-2.925 16.726,-23.907 40.413,-43.252 62.598,-56.915 m 66.319,124.848 c -21.364,59.109 -36.891,73.994 -60.249,73.994 h -0.049 c -22.772,-0.035 -30.72,-14.575 -9.433,-73.402 15.88,-43.925 36.497,-72.022 61.405,-72.022 h 0.033 c 23.688,0.036 29.121,13.904 8.293,71.43 m 73.39,-101.237 C 458.709,92.658 437.391,83.495 407.682,83.465 c -19.409,0 -38.258,4.505 -55.925,12.93 -25.282,12.078 -48.184,32.239 -66.907,58.989 -12.16,17.369 -22.544,37.479 -30.7,59.99 -15.365,42.488 -15.182,76.965 0.538,99.684 8.89,12.833 27.388,28.179 65.044,28.208 h 0.1 c 68.573,0 119.761,-45.377 152.132,-134.878 8.585,-23.7 19.868,-67.886 -0.766,-97.714"/>
            <path id="path440" d="m 695.906,87.206 c 4.88,3.903 9.092,8.352 12.604,13.449 8.962,13.062 12.404,28.596 10.365,46.392 h 45.949 l -69.277,192.239 h 69.211 l 69.294,-192.239 h 88.902 L 944.52,87.207 H 695.906 Z" style="fill:#ee7f00"/>
            <path style="fill:#3a3a3a" id="path446"
                  d="m -350.432,377.589 c -1.633,4.505 -3.674,7.67 -6.105,9.47 -2.432,1.808 -6.105,2.711 -11.016,2.711 -4.91,0 -7.917,-0.867 -8.977,-2.615 -1.065,-1.732 -0.803,-4.78 0.767,-9.173 1.667,-4.586 3.67,-7.757 6.07,-9.531 2.4,-1.763 6.059,-2.659 10.97,-2.659 4.915,0 7.917,0.862 9.028,2.563 1.11,1.711 0.866,4.78 -0.737,9.234 m -41.838,0 c -1.628,4.505 -3.636,7.67 -6.052,9.47 -2.4,1.808 -6.059,2.711 -10.969,2.711 -4.931,0 -7.917,-0.867 -9.013,-2.615 -1.106,-1.732 -0.862,-4.78 0.721,-9.173 1.649,-4.586 3.69,-7.757 6.105,-9.531 2.416,-1.763 6.069,-2.659 10.916,-2.659 4.98,0 8.017,0.862 9.082,2.563 1.074,1.711 0.812,4.78 -0.79,9.234 m 22.416,101.728 c -2.763,7.669 -6.368,14.528 -10.794,20.584 -4.403,6.074 -9.527,11.196 -15.388,15.375 -5.846,4.199 -12.359,7.379 -19.524,9.581 -7.181,2.187 -14.904,3.277 -23.196,3.277 -7.788,0 -14.431,-0.974 -19.914,-2.951 -5.486,-1.957 -9.645,-4.944 -12.489,-8.943 -2.823,-4.002 -4.291,-8.96 -4.421,-14.938 -0.115,-5.952 1.274,-12.924 4.143,-20.925 l 27.427,-76.1 c 0.244,-0.651 0.635,-1.222 1.205,-1.742 0.558,-0.505 1.404,-0.933 2.515,-1.258 1.096,-0.312 2.484,-0.576 4.148,-0.766 1.664,-0.198 3.735,-0.301 6.235,-0.301 2.434,0 4.406,0.103 5.925,0.301 1.519,0.189 2.709,0.454 3.56,0.766 0.828,0.325 1.371,0.753 1.595,1.258 0.229,0.521 0.229,1.091 0,1.742 l -26.62,73.866 c -1.793,4.976 -2.744,9.287 -2.839,12.91 -0.099,3.659 0.553,6.661 1.957,9.046 1.419,2.399 3.476,4.179 6.2,5.365 2.729,1.194 6.044,1.795 9.942,1.795 3.95,0 7.724,-0.616 11.281,-1.845 a 33.37,33.37 0 0 0 9.89,-5.371 c 3.006,-2.35 5.73,-5.24 8.164,-8.7 2.415,-3.445 4.423,-7.359 6.006,-11.752 l 27.13,-75.314 c 0.247,-0.651 0.637,-1.222 1.205,-1.742 0.576,-0.505 1.388,-0.933 2.464,-1.258 1.081,-0.312 2.469,-0.576 4.163,-0.766 1.682,-0.198 3.754,-0.301 6.169,-0.301 2.431,0 4.396,0.103 5.896,0.301 1.483,0.189 2.657,0.454 3.491,0.766 0.852,0.325 1.358,0.753 1.552,1.258 0.199,0.521 0.199,1.091 -0.048,1.742 z m 108.513,-43.62 c 0.897,-2.518 1.32,-4.75 1.271,-6.758 -0.035,-2.013 -0.588,-3.654 -1.648,-4.979 -1.061,-1.319 -2.615,-2.334 -4.687,-3.054 -2.087,-0.701 -5.058,-1.06 -8.959,-1.06 h -12.735 l -11.699,32.479 h 14.068 c 3.639,0 6.691,-0.424 9.176,-1.305 2.495,-0.866 4.716,-2.054 6.689,-3.572 a 24.63,24.63 0 0 0 5.14,-5.306 27.512,27.512 0 0 0 3.384,-6.445 m -12.896,53.572 c 1.027,-2.904 1.504,-5.483 1.351,-7.786 -0.13,-2.283 -0.844,-4.194 -2.118,-5.745 -1.304,-1.548 -3.236,-2.745 -5.815,-3.576 -2.576,-0.852 -6.151,-1.254 -10.738,-1.254 h -14.937 l -12.812,35.566 h 18.184 c 3.511,0 6.58,-0.355 9.243,-1.096 a 27.378,27.378 0 0 0 7.425,-3.298 c 2.265,-1.452 4.288,-3.26 6.069,-5.416 1.763,-2.156 3.137,-4.616 4.148,-7.395 m 26.442,-0.865 c -1.603,4.438 -3.659,8.469 -6.19,12.098 -2.51,3.589 -5.333,6.788 -8.469,9.565 a 56.37,56.37 0 0 1 -10.234,7.151 66.332,66.332 0 0 1 -11.589,4.922 75.339,75.339 0 0 1 -12.473,2.859 c -4.258,0.621 -8.894,0.917 -13.872,0.917 h -32.926 c -2.106,0 -3.656,-0.621 -4.653,-1.896 -0.975,-1.244 -0.945,-3.281 0.066,-6.136 l 39.308,-109.071 c 1.027,-2.828 2.48,-4.867 4.372,-6.142 1.895,-1.253 3.889,-1.876 5.991,-1.876 h 31.113 c 7.588,0 13.793,0.637 18.589,1.927 4.801,1.289 8.539,3.231 11.2,5.861 2.662,2.593 4.227,5.906 4.701,9.906 0.492,4.002 -0.244,8.7 -2.201,14.117 a 41.812,41.812 0 0 1 -4.249,8.558 42.258,42.258 0 0 1 -5.954,7.293 44.058,44.058 0 0 1 -7.509,5.814 c -2.745,1.681 -5.683,3.018 -8.782,4.046 3.267,0.652 6.09,1.779 8.491,3.395 2.38,1.621 4.21,3.69 5.499,6.238 1.289,2.548 1.958,5.529 2.006,8.944 0.035,3.415 -0.701,7.248 -2.235,11.51 m 92.59,27.561 c -0.667,1.859 -1.32,3.43 -1.926,4.683 -0.62,1.259 -1.211,2.268 -1.825,3.033 -0.591,0.789 -1.195,1.345 -1.801,1.701 -0.599,0.361 -1.19,0.54 -1.774,0.54 h -62.229 c -2.087,0 -3.636,-0.637 -4.617,-1.896 -0.997,-1.258 -0.981,-3.296 0.045,-6.135 l 39.308,-109.072 c 1.012,-2.844 2.484,-4.883 4.357,-6.137 1.893,-1.258 3.904,-1.896 6.007,-1.896 h 61.835 c 0.584,0 1.027,0.179 1.351,0.49 0.347,0.325 0.507,0.901 0.561,1.681 0.031,0.815 -0.117,1.859 -0.408,3.099 -0.297,1.274 -0.787,2.859 -1.488,4.786 -0.652,1.813 -1.29,3.348 -1.894,4.606 -0.622,1.249 -1.205,2.263 -1.812,3.047 -0.606,0.771 -1.189,1.327 -1.763,1.683 -0.569,0.356 -1.144,0.54 -1.733,0.54 h -44.218 l -11,30.553 h 37.428 c 0.576,0 1.029,0.184 1.388,0.524 0.344,0.358 0.553,0.917 0.606,1.646 0.046,0.754 -0.084,1.748 -0.376,3.008 -0.298,1.259 -0.752,2.776 -1.405,4.586 -0.688,1.875 -1.325,3.41 -1.926,4.639 -0.588,1.223 -1.178,2.216 -1.779,2.95 -0.573,0.738 -1.174,1.273 -1.764,1.605 -0.606,0.321 -1.174,0.488 -1.763,0.488 h -37.412 l -12.717,35.286 h 44.597 c 0.583,0 1.043,0.18 1.404,0.526 0.344,0.356 0.537,0.912 0.568,1.691 0.051,0.77 -0.079,1.8 -0.377,3.052 -0.304,1.246 -0.78,2.827 -1.448,4.693 m 118.103,-78.24 c 1.485,-4.112 1.83,-7.609 0.996,-10.433 -0.831,-2.839 -3.152,-4.831 -6.951,-6.003 -1.144,-0.326 -2.5,-0.571 -4.067,-0.771 -1.549,-0.192 -3.771,-0.291 -6.643,-0.291 h -11.298 l -12.779,35.486 h 12.833 c 3.576,0 6.836,-0.423 9.841,-1.304 3.002,-0.867 5.665,-2.096 8.016,-3.675 a 24.64,24.64 0 0 0 6.07,-5.667 c 1.678,-2.184 3.005,-4.631 3.982,-7.342 m 1.862,84.901 c -0.263,0.717 -0.606,1.319 -1.029,1.793 -0.429,0.475 -1.175,0.882 -2.253,1.212 -1.075,0.322 -2.549,0.551 -4.457,0.684 -1.896,0.113 -4.437,0.179 -7.642,0.179 -2.671,0 -4.795,-0.065 -6.345,-0.179 -1.535,-0.133 -2.709,-0.377 -3.511,-0.738 -0.801,-0.342 -1.291,-0.811 -1.484,-1.351 -0.183,-0.54 -0.244,-1.207 -0.229,-1.979 L -63.219,494.3 c -0.214,-3.165 -0.504,-5.974 -0.897,-8.42 -0.408,-2.451 -1.095,-4.49 -2.041,-6.135 -0.981,-1.651 -2.352,-2.874 -4.079,-3.711 -1.733,-0.846 -3.968,-1.27 -6.628,-1.27 h -7.854 l -17.185,47.661 c -0.232,0.657 -0.652,1.244 -1.244,1.748 -0.604,0.52 -1.434,0.928 -2.514,1.26 -1.061,0.325 -2.432,0.585 -4.113,0.779 -1.664,0.184 -3.735,0.28 -6.22,0.28 -2.431,0 -4.42,-0.097 -5.971,-0.28 -1.569,-0.194 -2.759,-0.454 -3.595,-0.779 -0.862,-0.332 -1.369,-0.74 -1.564,-1.26 -0.194,-0.504 -0.179,-1.091 0.051,-1.748 l 40.937,-113.611 c 1.027,-2.839 2.481,-4.878 4.377,-6.137 1.873,-1.253 3.884,-1.891 5.986,-1.891 h 32.078 c 3.247,0 5.907,0.082 7.964,0.21 a 89.78,89.78 0 0 1 5.567,0.478 c 4.734,0.699 8.764,1.942 12.129,3.67 3.361,1.743 5.922,4.016 7.688,6.825 1.764,2.808 2.692,6.119 2.791,9.941 0.079,3.849 -0.782,8.241 -2.561,13.199 -1.519,4.215 -3.415,8.017 -5.716,11.479 a 48.672,48.672 0 0 1 -7.963,9.225 c -3.022,2.709 -6.383,5.06 -10.108,7.067 -3.72,1.992 -7.718,3.609 -11.997,4.83 a 16.657,16.657 0 0 1 4.033,3.283 c 1.175,1.29 2.138,2.854 2.907,4.7 0.783,1.828 1.387,3.933 1.81,6.267 0.422,2.371 0.716,5.03 0.866,8.002 l 1.549,24.646 c 0.063,2.432 0.063,4.226 -0.031,5.351 -0.083,1.132 -0.243,2.028 -0.473,2.667 m 156.549,-3.192 c -0.928,1.556 -1.912,2.792 -2.938,3.727 -0.996,0.927 -2.255,1.645 -3.774,2.119 -1.518,0.494 -3.361,0.815 -5.514,0.979 -2.157,0.169 -4.88,0.245 -8.126,0.245 -3.644,0 -6.534,-0.076 -8.669,-0.245 -2.14,-0.163 -3.773,-0.484 -4.869,-0.979 -1.106,-0.475 -1.779,-1.192 -2.018,-2.119 -0.23,-0.935 -0.23,-2.171 0,-3.727 l 8.76,-79.278 H 93.97 l -47.34,79.278 c -0.851,1.488 -1.733,2.711 -2.645,3.623 -0.915,0.953 -2.087,1.667 -3.506,2.171 -1.442,0.525 -3.251,0.867 -5.455,1.03 -2.187,0.169 -5.046,0.245 -8.552,0.245 -3.69,0 -6.627,-0.076 -8.768,-0.245 -2.151,-0.163 -3.769,-0.484 -4.864,-0.979 -1.106,-0.475 -1.779,-1.192 -2.003,-2.119 -0.244,-0.935 -0.283,-2.171 -0.099,-3.727 L 21.93,410.281 c 0.265,-2.329 0.588,-4.163 1.012,-5.467 0.413,-1.321 1.129,-2.345 2.21,-3.054 1.042,-0.698 2.509,-1.141 4.388,-1.304 1.862,-0.159 4.441,-0.246 7.688,-0.246 3.004,0 5.354,0.046 7.086,0.147 1.712,0.099 2.954,0.327 3.736,0.668 0.751,0.378 1.175,0.882 1.258,1.57 0.084,0.668 -0.015,1.615 -0.262,2.839 l -12.814,95.821 h 0.114 l 56.873,-95.154 c 0.683,-1.202 1.387,-2.217 2.087,-2.981 0.688,-0.769 1.603,-1.376 2.745,-1.783 1.144,-0.424 2.593,-0.718 4.388,-0.881 1.782,-0.159 4.097,-0.246 6.975,-0.246 3.067,0 5.484,0.066 7.262,0.199 1.776,0.133 3.071,0.408 3.915,0.815 0.835,0.423 1.327,1.028 1.503,1.794 0.164,0.77 0.148,1.809 -0.066,3.083 l -10.918,95.154 h 0.199 l 56.146,-95.546 c 0.56,-1.01 1.128,-1.891 1.732,-2.646 0.571,-0.728 1.388,-1.319 2.434,-1.727 1.042,-0.424 2.431,-0.718 4.148,-0.881 1.712,-0.159 4.06,-0.246 7.081,-0.246 2.793,0 4.949,0.087 6.467,0.246 1.496,0.163 2.478,0.605 2.938,1.304 0.421,0.709 0.354,1.764 -0.232,3.155 -0.604,1.371 -1.616,3.262 -3.052,5.646 z m 129.844,-3.469 a 50.994,50.994 0 0 1 -1.923,4.683 c -0.622,1.259 -1.213,2.268 -1.833,3.033 -0.586,0.789 -1.19,1.345 -1.797,1.701 -0.599,0.361 -1.189,0.54 -1.778,0.54 h -62.221 c -2.09,0 -3.639,-0.637 -4.635,-1.896 -0.981,-1.258 -0.966,-3.296 0.063,-6.135 l 39.306,-109.072 c 1.011,-2.844 2.484,-4.883 4.357,-6.137 1.896,-1.258 3.904,-1.896 6.006,-1.896 h 61.836 c 0.586,0 1.029,0.179 1.353,0.49 0.344,0.325 0.52,0.901 0.558,1.681 0.016,0.815 -0.114,1.859 -0.413,3.099 -0.292,1.274 -0.782,2.859 -1.483,4.786 a 41.888,41.888 0 0 1 -1.909,4.606 c -0.591,1.249 -1.189,2.263 -1.796,3.047 -0.604,0.771 -1.195,1.327 -1.764,1.683 -0.567,0.356 -1.159,0.54 -1.732,0.54 H 237.13 l -11.016,30.553 h 37.428 c 0.591,0 1.03,0.184 1.404,0.524 0.344,0.358 0.538,0.917 0.591,1.646 0.062,0.754 -0.069,1.748 -0.361,3.008 -0.296,1.259 -0.751,2.776 -1.404,4.586 -0.688,1.875 -1.325,3.41 -1.924,4.639 -0.606,1.223 -1.195,2.216 -1.782,2.95 -0.588,0.738 -1.156,1.273 -1.763,1.605 -0.604,0.321 -1.19,0.488 -1.764,0.488 h -37.427 l -12.718,35.286 h 44.598 c 0.583,0 1.042,0.18 1.404,0.526 0.339,0.356 0.538,0.912 0.583,1.691 0.054,0.77 -0.079,1.8 -0.374,3.052 -0.292,1.246 -0.784,2.827 -1.452,4.693 m 53.402,6.471 c -0.23,0.652 -0.638,1.229 -1.244,1.748 -0.604,0.504 -1.435,0.927 -2.515,1.238 -1.075,0.327 -2.431,0.587 -4.11,0.785 -1.667,0.194 -3.738,0.296 -6.217,0.296 -2.431,0 -4.424,-0.102 -5.976,-0.296 -1.564,-0.198 -2.759,-0.458 -3.605,-0.785 -0.852,-0.312 -1.389,-0.734 -1.604,-1.238 -0.244,-0.52 -0.229,-1.096 0,-1.748 l 42.575,-118.169 c 0.239,-0.632 0.652,-1.219 1.253,-1.728 0.604,-0.52 1.472,-0.928 2.562,-1.253 1.111,-0.332 2.484,-0.592 4.164,-0.786 1.666,-0.182 3.707,-0.29 6.138,-0.29 2.479,0 4.488,0.108 6.021,0.29 1.52,0.194 2.709,0.454 3.545,0.786 0.851,0.325 1.389,0.733 1.618,1.253 0.224,0.509 0.224,1.096 -0.021,1.728 z m 122.602,-34.032 c -2.386,6.578 -5.683,12.342 -9.877,17.307 -4.228,4.979 -8.992,9.106 -14.347,12.42 -5.341,3.327 -11.103,5.83 -17.253,7.506 a 71.247,71.247 0 0 1 -18.709,2.498 c -4.273,0 -8.126,-0.361 -11.538,-1.06 -3.414,-0.704 -6.353,-1.551 -8.798,-2.548 -2.435,-1.011 -4.406,-2.055 -5.892,-3.15 -1.488,-1.091 -2.518,-2.06 -3.022,-2.906 -0.522,-0.83 -0.7,-2.038 -0.472,-3.623 0.209,-1.584 0.847,-3.852 1.927,-6.824 0.716,-1.992 1.383,-3.673 2.005,-5.014 0.619,-1.365 1.226,-2.462 1.814,-3.293 0.587,-0.852 1.175,-1.441 1.797,-1.778 0.599,-0.361 1.221,-0.546 1.857,-0.546 0.896,0 1.962,0.546 3.213,1.59 1.243,1.075 2.908,2.254 5,3.543 2.089,1.274 4.719,2.461 7.866,3.521 3.151,1.064 7.071,1.604 11.721,1.604 3.068,0 5.938,-0.376 8.637,-1.13 2.708,-0.734 5.124,-1.779 7.31,-3.135 a 22.674,22.674 0 0 0 5.678,-5.025 23.005,23.005 0 0 0 3.759,-6.677 c 1.029,-2.844 1.126,-5.254 0.323,-7.292 -0.797,-2.044 -2.135,-3.842 -4.028,-5.407 -1.893,-1.601 -4.148,-3.067 -6.758,-4.46 a 329.115,329.115 0 0 1 -8.101,-4.402 53.843,53.843 0 0 1 -7.765,-5.274 22.938,22.938 0 0 1 -5.845,-7.054 c -1.471,-2.737 -2.286,-5.973 -2.485,-9.724 -0.175,-3.727 0.673,-8.211 2.568,-13.435 2.151,-5.993 5.14,-11.263 8.994,-15.818 3.834,-4.542 8.161,-8.308 12.978,-11.3 4.811,-3 10.019,-5.238 15.635,-6.722 a 65.698,65.698 0 0 1 16.93,-2.221 c 2.938,0 5.777,0.229 8.567,0.673 2.778,0.452 5.287,1.06 7.572,1.844 2.256,0.765 4.213,1.631 5.847,2.61 1.633,0.963 2.66,1.764 3.053,2.399 0.407,0.652 0.637,1.208 0.697,1.662 0.069,0.442 0.039,1.05 -0.061,1.777 -0.1,0.755 -0.329,1.683 -0.686,2.81 a 95.127,95.127 0 0 1 -1.404,4.215 c -0.688,1.859 -1.31,3.444 -1.862,4.714 -0.574,1.304 -1.096,2.369 -1.618,3.199 -0.535,0.837 -1.072,1.458 -1.634,1.85 a 3.258,3.258 0 0 1 -1.872,0.566 c -0.704,0 -1.665,-0.438 -2.875,-1.335 -1.189,-0.912 -2.724,-1.896 -4.587,-2.956 -1.842,-1.08 -4.082,-2.038 -6.706,-2.905 -2.614,-0.881 -5.683,-1.305 -9.191,-1.305 -2.744,0 -5.274,0.343 -7.54,1.016 -2.301,0.683 -4.342,1.61 -6.137,2.803 -1.796,1.191 -3.35,2.628 -4.604,4.306 a 19.087,19.087 0 0 0 -2.938,5.326 c -0.997,2.762 -1.111,5.172 -0.344,7.194 0.767,2.023 2.117,3.839 4.082,5.423 1.939,1.565 4.258,3.054 6.967,4.44 a 281.633,281.633 0 0 1 8.162,4.393 61.19,61.19 0 0 1 7.884,5.27 c 2.479,1.977 4.472,4.326 5.976,7.068 1.503,2.742 2.334,5.958 2.548,9.662 0.191,3.706 -0.621,8.085 -2.418,13.11 m 131.776,-9.087 c -2.777,7.669 -6.368,14.528 -10.771,20.584 -4.426,6.074 -9.551,11.196 -15.411,15.375 -5.846,4.199 -12.341,7.379 -19.521,9.581 -7.181,2.187 -14.904,3.277 -23.213,3.277 -7.77,0 -14.413,-0.974 -19.899,-2.951 -5.483,-1.957 -9.645,-4.944 -12.489,-8.943 -2.823,-4.002 -4.303,-8.96 -4.402,-14.938 -0.131,-5.952 1.256,-12.924 4.128,-20.925 l 27.423,-76.1 c 0.23,-0.651 0.622,-1.222 1.206,-1.742 0.573,-0.505 1.403,-0.933 2.499,-1.258 1.111,-0.312 2.5,-0.576 4.164,-0.766 1.682,-0.198 3.753,-0.301 6.237,-0.301 2.432,0 4.404,0.103 5.923,0.301 1.518,0.189 2.708,0.454 3.56,0.766 0.83,0.325 1.365,0.753 1.58,1.258 0.247,0.521 0.247,1.091 0,1.742 l -26.604,73.866 c -1.796,4.976 -2.744,9.287 -2.843,12.91 -0.095,3.659 0.558,6.661 1.961,9.046 1.404,2.399 3.477,4.179 6.2,5.365 2.729,1.194 6.042,1.795 9.94,1.795 3.935,0 7.708,-0.616 11.283,-1.845 a 33.468,33.468 0 0 0 9.89,-5.371 c 3.021,-2.35 5.746,-5.24 8.162,-8.7 2.415,-3.445 4.426,-7.359 6.006,-11.752 l 27.148,-75.314 c 0.229,-0.651 0.621,-1.222 1.189,-1.742 0.573,-0.505 1.389,-0.933 2.462,-1.258 1.08,-0.312 2.469,-0.576 4.165,-0.766 1.695,-0.198 3.752,-0.301 6.167,-0.301 2.434,0 4.396,0.103 5.899,0.301 1.48,0.189 2.655,0.454 3.49,0.766 0.852,0.325 1.356,0.753 1.551,1.258 0.213,0.521 0.197,1.091 -0.031,1.742 z m 124.18,37.702 c -0.538,1.487 -1.256,2.808 -2.202,3.965 a 13.971,13.971 0 0 1 -3.088,2.894 11.78,11.78 0 0 1 -3.67,1.693 c -1.324,0.361 -2.563,0.54 -3.789,0.54 h -10.722 c -2.235,0 -4.083,-0.23 -5.551,-0.683 a 7.067,7.067 0 0 1 -3.61,-2.468 c -0.943,-1.177 -1.68,-2.787 -2.232,-4.83 -0.538,-2.023 -1.03,-4.654 -1.457,-7.869 l -9.758,-58.516 a 216.693,216.693 0 0 1 -1.388,-11.248 149.118,149.118 0 0 1 -0.736,-11.757 h -0.194 a 587.058,587.058 0 0 1 -4.424,13.877 684.144,684.144 0 0 1 -4.964,14.271 l -23.588,65.457 c -0.225,0.637 -0.617,1.218 -1.145,1.742 -0.535,0.504 -1.305,0.933 -2.301,1.289 -0.977,0.357 -2.247,0.638 -3.766,0.831 -1.552,0.199 -3.477,0.296 -5.777,0.296 -2.225,0 -4.036,-0.097 -5.44,-0.296 -1.386,-0.193 -2.445,-0.474 -3.151,-0.831 -0.699,-0.356 -1.106,-0.785 -1.252,-1.289 -0.13,-0.524 -0.084,-1.105 0.146,-1.742 l 40.528,-112.456 c 1.096,-3.033 2.777,-5.306 5.079,-6.825 2.301,-1.498 4.747,-2.262 7.295,-2.262 h 13.5 c 2.416,0 4.389,0.194 5.892,0.617 1.503,0.422 2.744,1.125 3.705,2.089 0.951,0.963 1.697,2.304 2.239,4.015 0.523,1.698 0.946,3.803 1.26,6.337 l 7.634,45.719 c 0.413,2.776 0.818,5.498 1.226,8.179 0.408,2.675 0.783,5.353 1.091,8.032 0.313,2.66 0.606,5.285 0.882,7.883 0.299,2.565 0.543,5.139 0.767,7.718 h 0.084 c 1.435,-4.5 2.984,-9.204 4.65,-14.117 a 992.265,992.265 0 0 1 4.916,-14.006 l 21.157,-58.699 c 0.229,-0.652 0.634,-1.224 1.205,-1.748 0.558,-0.504 1.355,-0.958 2.4,-1.351 1.042,-0.377 2.316,-0.651 3.835,-0.82 1.534,-0.163 3.445,-0.244 5.746,-0.244 2.155,0 3.95,0.081 5.354,0.244 1.42,0.169 2.449,0.443 3.102,0.82 0.667,0.393 1.058,0.847 1.19,1.351 0.149,0.524 0.081,1.096 -0.148,1.748 z m 170.311,-96.791 c -0.668,1.883 -1.331,3.478 -1.993,4.833 -0.642,1.351 -1.259,2.451 -1.814,3.246 -0.591,0.806 -1.142,1.371 -1.682,1.701 -0.535,0.307 -1.08,0.47 -1.646,0.47 -0.835,0 -1.957,-0.586 -3.408,-1.742 -1.422,-1.143 -3.436,-2.401 -5.994,-3.773 -2.578,-1.335 -5.794,-2.607 -9.602,-3.771 -3.832,-1.161 -8.551,-1.728 -14.18,-1.728 a 49.317,49.317 0 0 0 -17.399,3.135 c -5.601,2.09 -10.81,5.057 -15.655,8.893 -4.835,3.833 -9.144,8.456 -12.912,13.827 -3.789,5.386 -6.872,11.328 -9.222,17.837 -2.576,7.165 -3.903,13.47 -3.98,18.922 -0.084,5.433 0.912,10.004 2.969,13.663 2.056,3.686 5.124,6.448 9.207,8.329 4.079,1.869 8.989,2.808 14.735,2.808 2.792,0 5.715,-0.332 8.689,-0.969 a 43.055,43.055 0 0 0 8.699,-2.904 l 10.442,-29.009 h -23.453 c -1.142,0 -1.778,-0.714 -1.894,-2.187 -0.13,-1.447 0.454,-3.898 1.713,-7.395 0.652,-1.794 1.271,-3.313 1.878,-4.536 0.588,-1.237 1.19,-2.206 1.763,-2.956 0.606,-0.732 1.176,-1.288 1.748,-1.631 0.571,-0.356 1.16,-0.54 1.728,-0.54 h 41.841 c 1.01,0 1.855,0.184 2.527,0.54 0.669,0.343 1.173,0.862 1.535,1.586 0.356,0.718 0.504,1.564 0.453,2.559 -0.03,0.998 -0.275,2.14 -0.733,3.444 l -17.949,49.786 c -0.693,1.941 -1.651,3.644 -2.826,5.076 -1.211,1.452 -2.992,2.595 -5.376,3.444 -2.362,0.831 -5.255,1.698 -8.632,2.61 a 141.156,141.156 0 0 1 -10.363,2.318 127.042,127.042 0 0 1 -10.48,1.442 c -3.46,0.321 -6.888,0.49 -10.284,0.49 -9.889,0 -18.234,-1.443 -25.008,-4.298 -6.79,-2.889 -11.915,-7.033 -15.375,-12.471 -3.461,-5.447 -5.209,-12.093 -5.26,-19.931 -0.049,-7.833 1.718,-16.717 5.29,-26.639 3.689,-10.253 8.539,-19.443 14.529,-27.602 6.006,-8.165 12.843,-15.086 20.516,-20.8 7.692,-5.706 16.03,-10.069 25.073,-13.103 9.047,-3.021 18.429,-4.54 28.206,-4.54 5.356,0 10.106,0.377 14.234,1.127 4.133,0.733 7.654,1.635 10.564,2.691 2.905,1.06 5.219,2.221 6.951,3.429 1.712,1.243 2.854,2.288 3.395,3.201 0.54,0.896 0.703,2.171 0.488,3.815 -0.213,1.658 -0.896,4.088 -2.053,7.303"/>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </v-icon>
```

If I put the same svg into an `v-img`tag the image is displayed perfectly, i.e.

```
      <v-img>
        <svg ... /svg>
      </v-img>
```

Does anyone has a clue what the problem is? My ultimate goal is to display the icon in a button.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom component for your svg:

*MyIcon.vue*

```html
<template functional>
  <svg class="custom-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="264">
    ...
  </svg>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
<style lang="scss">
.custom-icon {
  fill: currentColor
}
</style>
```

then in *src/plugins/vuetify.js* import it:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import MyIcon from './MyIcon.vue'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    values: {
      myIcon: {
        component: MyIcon
      },
    },
  },
})
```

then you can use it:

```html
<v-icon>$myIcon</v-icon>
```

**Reference [link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icons/#component-icons)**

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Kudos to you. Just wanted to add that in my particular example I had another problem with SVG scaling. https://wattenberger.com/guide/scaling-svg helped me to resolve the scaling problem.

Comment: @BorIs you can use size in v-icon if you want to change size.

Comment: Do you mean the small, medium, large flags? That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If it doesn't work you have to change your svg based on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The default slot of `v-icon` accepts only a name of built-in icon component like `md-home` or `fas fa-home`, you could create your own icon component that accepts the svg as default slot :

```
<template>
<v-img>
    <slot></slot>
</v-img>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "my-icon",
};
</script>
```

then use it like :

```
  <my-icon>
    <svg ... /svg>
  </my-icon>
```